# Render a partial from within a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a complex form so I'd like to split it into manageable sections. Problem is that `render` is throwing an error.

**structure:**

```
>app
  >views
   >quote
     _form.html.erb
       >forms
         _contact_form.html.erb
         _products_form.html.erb
          . . .
```

Inside of `_form.html.erb` I have the following:

```
<%= render partial: '/forms/contact_form' %>
```

And I get: `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error.

**What is the best way to modularize a large form/view to make it manageable?** And if I can't render a partial from within a partial; how should it be done?

*fixed typo*

I meant this: `<%= render partial: '/forms/contact_form' %>` doesn't work (_ removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to render a partial from partial without any problems.

This is how to render a partial with the proper path:

- `<%= render partial: 'quote/forms/contact_form' %>`

Comment: Hey, neither option is working for me. What else can it be?  `ActionView::MissingTemplate` is my error.

Comment: Either your structure is not correct, or something else is making this problem.

Comment: How can I debug? ideas?

Comment: Show us the complete path from your application root folder to the partial.

Comment: I got it working by taking it out of the `forms` dir and placing it directly into the `quote` dir. I am able to render it as: `<%= render partial: 'contact' %>` However it does not work under the forms dir. Idea?

Comment: Not really. When you are referencing the partials in rails, there are only 2 possibilities: 1) put it in the same folder and reference just by name of the partial, 2) put it in any folder and reference by the relative path to the app/views folder.

Comment: Check the error page as well.  It should give you an indicator of the paths it's searching and maybe that will illuminate what's going on. It seems like the full path '/quote/forms/contact_form' *should* work unless `app/views/quote/forms/_contact_form.html.erb` is not present.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. I got it working. update your answer to remove the first '/' as: `<%= render partial: 'quote/forms/contact_form' %>` This is the proper path. Thanks.

Comment: In your question, you don't show the views dir in the dir tree.  is that just a typo?  or are you putting your views under app/quote/...?  If so, that might be the root of the issue, though that would probably cause bigger problems.